# Active Admin : How to restrict active admin routes in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancancan

I developed a normal (Post) like rails application that has features of posting articles with pictures then I opted for active admin in regulating the post as in (admin user), so the application doesnt have any other user expect the admin that will regulate post at backend, how do I restrict these admin routes page like if a normal web visitor attempts to visit the routes it wont be accessible ?

```
new_admin_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)                                                                            active_admin/devise/sessions#new
                  admin_user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)                                                                            active_admin/devise/sessions#create
          destroy_admin_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)                                                                           active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
             new_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)                                                                     active_admin/devise/passwords#new
            edit_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)                                                                    active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                 admin_user_password PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)                                                                         active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                                     PUT        /admin/password(.:format)                                                                         active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                                     POST       /admin/password(.:format)                                                                         active_admin/devise/passwords#create
                          admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                                                                                  admin/dashboard#index
      batch_action_admin_admin_users POST       /admin/admin_users/batch_action(.:format)                                                         admin/admin_users#batch_action
                   admin_admin_users GET        /admin/admin_users(.:format)                                                                      admin/admin_users#index
                                     POST       /admin/admin_users(.:format)                                                                      admin/admin_users#create
                new_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/new(.:format)                                                                  admin/admin_users#new
               edit_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             admin/admin_users#edit
                    admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)                                                                  admin/admin_users#show
                                     PATCH      /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)                                                                  admin/admin_users#update
                                     PUT        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)                                                                  admin/admin_users#update
                                     DELETE     /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)                                                                  admin/admin_users#destroy
         batch_action_admin_articles POST       /admin/articles/batch_action(.:format)                                                            admin/articles#batch_action
                      admin_articles GET        /admin/articles(.:format)                                                                         admin/articles#index
                                     POST       /admin/articles(.:format)                                                                         admin/articles#create
                   new_admin_article GET        /admin/articles/new(.:format)                                                                     admin/articles#new
                  edit_admin_article GET        /admin/articles/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                admin/articles#edit
                       admin_article GET        /admin/articles/:id(.:format)                                                                     admin/articles#show
                                     PATCH      /admin/articles/:id(.:format)                                                                     admin/articles#update
                                     PUT        /admin/articles/:id(.:format)                                                                     admin/articles#update
                                     DELETE     /admin/articles/:id(.:format)                                                                     admin/articles#destroy
                     admin_dashboard GET        /admin/dashboard(.:format)                                                                        admin/dashboard#index
                      admin_comments GET        /admin/comments(.:format)                                                                         admin/comments#index
                                     POST       /admin/comments(.:format)                                                                         admin/comments#create
                       admin_c
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way i have seen is by integrating an authorization system in AA, here is the link:

https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html#managing-access-to-pages